# Wrong CRS in map with QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg, position

I have made a raster elevation map of Greenland, and have information of the region, cities and more as vectors. The information is not in the same place as my elevation map.

I have selected EPSG:5938 on the bottom right in QGIS and on my informations and elevation map I have set the CRS to the same like the picture

[image: HERE]

How do I get it all on the same position?

Comment: Never ever just SET the CRS of a layer to something else. Always reproject/transform them - if necessary. QGIS is able to reproject data on the fly, meaning that data in different CRS at the same place is displayed correctly.

Comment: I suspect that your elevation data is a TIF, JPG, or PNG with an associated world file.  These types of data will not 'project on the fly'.  Instead, the GIS will use the world file to draw the raster in the correct location given the project's coordinate reference system(CRS).  Figure out the CRS of your surface.  Set the project to that CRS, then add the shapefiles and see if things line up.